# 404 Error - Uploading file size greater than 30 MB

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, filesize, upload-max-filesize

In our Web API, we can not upload fize size which is more than 30MB. We used to get 404 Error such as "**404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**"

By Googling and seeing various post, I tired the below changes in my config file:

### Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" timeout="7200" />
</system.web>
<requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" maxQueryString="2097151" maxUrl="10999"/>
</requestFiltering>
```

But still, I could not upload file which is more than 30MB size. But the same code is working fine to upload file which is below 30 MB.

Any thing that i had missed here?

Comment: Ressource not found when it is actually just too big? Seems odd to me. Wouldn´t be 413 (request entity too large) be more approriate?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Open IIS Manager.

2.) Select the website that you want to configure.

3.) Make sure you are in Features View per the button at the bottom of the manager.

4.) Select Requests Filtering and open it by double-clicking the icon. The Request Filtering pane displays.

5.) From the Actions pane on the right hand side of the screen click Edit Feature Settings... link. The Edit Request Filtering Settings window displays.

6.) In the Request Limits section, enter the appropriate Maximum allowed content length (Bytes) and then click the OK button.
Restart IIS.

This worked for me :)

Comment: Is it a 404.13? Try restarting server.

Comment: You 100% certain you configured the right website. This worked instantly yesterday when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your web.config to use `system.webServer` and `security`?

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting in what worked for me.
I had to make two changes:

update `web.config` with following settings:

```xml
<system.webServer>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
```

But using just this was not working for me. I had to add another attribute to API Controller to make it work.

```cs
[HttpPost]
//[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestSizeLimit(70_000_000)] //Files sizes upto 70 MB are allowed
```

My setup was Blazor WebAssembly template with ASP Hosted option. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Another source I found useful and relevant: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/